# XElement.Element error

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml

I get a "Object not set to an...." when I try to do this. The exceptions hits me on the last line.

```
xml.Add(new XElement("Root", ""));
xml.Element("Root").Add(new XElement("Sites", ""));
xmlContent = xmlContent.Element("Root").Element("Sites");
```

Anyone ?

Comment: You haven't shown where `xmlContent` is coming from. A short but *complete* program would really help...

Comment: Problem solved. 

xml.Add(new XElement("Root", "")); xml.Element("Root").Add(new XElement("Sites", "")); xmlContent = xml.Element("Root").Element("Sites");

Comment: That doesn't really help anyone seeing this question in the future, as you still haven't explained where `xml` and `xmlContent` came from in the first place. For future questions, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlContent` is `null` or `xmlElement` doesn't contain an element named `Root`. That's all I can say from that little code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

From:

```
xml.Add(new XElement("Root", ""));
xml.Element("Root").Add(new XElement("Sites", ""));
xmlContent = xmlContent.Element("Root").Element("Sites");
```

To:

```
xml.Add(new XElement("Root", ""));
xml.Element("Root").Add(new XElement("Sites", ""));
xmlContent = xml.Element("Root").Element("Sites");
```

I just needed to use the correct instance, xml and not xmlContent.

Thanks!